# Avoid discretization error in ssas

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, ssas-2012

I have a dimension with attribute AGE.
I have applied discretization on that attribute where the bucket count is 20.
Everything works fine when we have enough values for AGE column in the underlying database.
But recently we updated the table and none but one row has value in AGE column.
Now I am getting processing  error saying there is not enough value to create the bucket.

Can I bypass this error and still process the cube? I want the cube not to give processing error even if we do not have enough data in the underlying table to create buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The only way is to re-tune DiscretizationMethod property to None manually.

I also tried changing directly in XML:
[image: Discretization_1Initial]

From `Automatic` to `None`:

[image: Discretization_2Try]

But **failed** as expected: no changes were applied.